# Vaadin Application Bug: No UI was found based on data in the request

Tags: java, google-chrome, netbeans, vaadin, payara

I am on a team that is building a Vaadin Application using Netbeans IDE 8.1 with a Payara GlassFish Server (version 4.1.1.161.1) and an up-to-date Chrome browser.

The problem occurs when I run the application after cleaning and building all the projects. All the **event listeners on the starting UI are unresponsive** and after closing the tab this appears in the server console log:

`Info: No UI was found based on data in the request, but a slower lookup based on the AtmosphereResource succeeded. See http://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/14251 for more details.`

Interesting thing is that another member of the team has the same base code and it **works perfectly fine on his machine** (which has the same specs as mine). Anyone have any ideas on what could be different between our machines or why this bug is happening?

**Update:** The buttons become responsive as soon as I get rid of the push enabled annotation. Any ideas as to why `@Push` causes the listeners to become unresponsive?

Comment: If you are leaving the client page open in chrome when you rebuild it may have some static data that is inconsistant. You could close the chrome page when you rebuild. You could download the source for vaadin-server and put a break point on the method com.vaadin.server.communication.PushHandler.connectionLost()  which seems to have this message logged from it and see if you can get more info from the debugger.

Comment: The problem is that a login button for the page doesn't even register on the click listener. No AJAX events are fired (the application is push-enabled). I put a breakpoint like you mentioned and when closing the session, the breakpoint is caught then. When i try to get the uiIdString from the VaadinRequest Object it returns null.